# How to Create DataBase in SQLite, implement ADD EDIT DELETE using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, sqlite

I'm currently using ionic (HTML5, CSS, AngularJS) to create my first android app, this application allows me to create a database and add names quiz exams attendance etc. My problem is I'm new to this sqlite database, and i already watched some tutorials for javascript and sqlite but I'm still having a hard time figuring the sequence of the program, some of the tutorials requires me to open the database before inserting something, and some does not. So, can anyone give me a sample code for creating a database and for the syntax of add edit and delete. I hope someone can help me. I highly appreciate any help that i can get just to improve my skills, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using web-sql

```
var db = openDatabase('name-db', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024 (2mb));
```

[Web-SQL tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

I highly recommend to use this Database library [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/)

```
var db = new PouchDB('dbname');

db.put({
  _id: 'dave@gmail.com',
  name: 'David',
  age: 68
});

db.changes().on('change', function() {
   console.log('Ch-Ch-Changes');
});
```

Comment: ok ill look in to it, but I'm still looking for the SQLite tutorials or codes to help me in my work. Thank you :) i do have 1 question, have you already used PouchDB?   @BlaShadow

Comment: Yes, it got a pretty cool abstraction of html5 databases, and you can use it without couchDB, couchdb db its just a feature on that library.

Also you need to take care that web-sql only works on a few devices http://caniuse.com/#search=websql